# Backup drive spindown : is it harmfull?

Tags: backup, hard-drive

I plan on doing a small, Raspberry PI4 based backup server for my house using USB external drives. My plan is to have each PC (4 of them) backing up to the server automatically every month. The rest of the time the drives would not be accessed or written to. Since I want the server to be as efficient as possible (in terms of power consumption), and with the least noise possible, I was considering spinning down the RAID 1 array as long as they are not used, and basically have them spinning up once a month for the backup, and then back down.
I've been searching the internet for a while now, and I think I've found as many "its fine" answers as I've found "it'll kill your drives prematurely"...

What's your take on this ?

Comment: What does spinning the drives down have to do with efficiency? How does this make the server or the drives any more or less efficient? Efficient in what sense?

Comment: @joeqwerty sorry, i'll clarify this in the post. I meant it in a power consumption way. Stopped drives dont use as much power

Comment: In my case, I put the drive in idle mode 3 minutes after the end of the usage. As you use the drive once a month, it will be happy for a long time. Don forget smart to check it healthy when it is alive. The Raspi4 will (I think) consume much more energy. Maybe a Raspi3 is sufficient ?

Comment: @Dom The pi4 has a few features I consider essential, like Gig ethernet and USB3 ports (pi3 is 100Mb and usb2. It also shares bandwidth between the lan and the USB ports). But technically you are right, a PI3 would use less power... One important pont too is that i got a pi4 for free lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all let's clarify how "dangerous" are the spin downs. Most drives today are designed for a lot of spin-up cycles. It depends on the drive but they usually handle anything from 100.000 to 1000.000 cycles.

Every drive has an idle timeout after which it spins itself down. They are designed to do this many times every day.
On most drives you can even change this timeout witch `smartctl` or `hdparm`.

While technically you can stop the raid array, it won't matter if really nothing is touching these files.
If you want to be extra careful and prevent cron jobs, or a wild `find` command to wake up the disks, you can just `umount` the mount point, which is much quicker and easier than stopping the array.

The only exception is the (usually) monthly RAID scrub, which means you would get two spin-ups per month.
But these scrubs can help you identify failing hardware before it's too late, so a monthly run is recommended, and won't really affect your disks life span.

Comment: This is reassuring, thanks for your time !